Modify VSCode Intellisense for JS/TS Doc?
Does anyone know if it is possible to modify VSCode Intellisense for JSDoc and TSDoc tags? I have always been bothered by the way VSCode handles certain JS/TS doc tags and I just cannot handle it anymore.
As trivial as it might sound, when documenting custom type and interface definitions, I just want the @property tag to be formatted in the same manner as the @param tag. The following screen shots illustrate my issue:

Notice the emdash — between the @property tags and the keys being described above?

See how it's placed after the @param tags and the respective keys?
Does anyone know how to make this change?

I'd open an issue on the vscode repo

This change would have to be in VSCode, specifically in getTagDocumentation

if you open an issue ticket, please add a link here to it. I think the right place to open this would be in typescript's github repo, but don't quote me on that.
